# Send and receive in loop in MPI

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

this is my code, I am trying to change the processor in a loop so that the other processor can continue the loop until is finished, meaning only one processor can increse the value of `l`...
but I the program gets stock after some values....
what is the problem and how should I solve it
is it even possible to do this?

```
  while(l<100)
{
    
    if (my_rank == current_rank)
    {
        old_rank = current_rank;
        current_rank = (rand())%(p -0 +1) + 0;
        l = l+1;
        printf("l is: %d\n", l);
        printf("current rank is: %d\n", current_rank);
        for (int i = 0; i < p; i++)
        {
            if(i != my_rank)
            {
                MPI_Send(&current_rank, 1, MPI_INT, i, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                MPI_Send(&l, 1, MPI_INT, i, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
               
         
                

            }
                
        }
        
        
    }
    else
    {
        MPI_Recv(&current_rank, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&l, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        
  
    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: make sure all the ranks see the same `current_rank`. if you are still stuck, please edit your question with a [mcve]

Comment: I am sending the current rank after it changes to all other processors, and after that all other processors receive it...

Comment: so post a [mcve]

Comment: *meaning only one processor can increse the value of l* This smells very fishy to me.  It looks as if the code is trying to implement some version of a global variable.  Yes, that can be done, but it cuts against the grain of MPI where the sweet spots are closer to independent execution of all processes at all times.  I may well have misinterpreted the code so by all means ignore this comment. But if I haven't, perhaps explain why you are trying to code the way your are coding, you may have encountered an *x-y problem*.